# Getting 404 in WebSocket connection

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

I have a backend java code for websocket.

SessionEndpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/session")
public class SessionEndpoint {

    private static Set<SessionEndpoint> sessionEndpoints = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String sessionId) {
        Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put("sessionId", sessionId);

        sessionEndpoints.forEach(endpoint -> {
            synchronized (endpoint) {
                try {
                    session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(attributes);
                } catch (IOException | EncodeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Trying to connect to websocket from javascript, code is given below.

```
let webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9999/session');
webSocket.onopen = () => webSocket.send('hello');

webSocket.onmessage = function(response) {
    console.log(response);
};
```

I get 404 response code while connecting to websocket. How should I connect to webscoket from javascript ?

Comment: I have two different servers for backend and frontend

Comment: have you solved this using @ServerEndpoint? I have also tried creating a server in java using this method but it seems to be totally ignored. Using the WebSocketConfiguration + Controller seems to work fine.